# as3 - Constructor Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, constructor

I've got (to me) a strange error. As far as I can tell I'm doing everything correct, however I keep getting the error bellow.

> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Enemy().
> Expected 2, got 0.

As you can see, when initializing my class Enemy it expects two arguments and gets one. However, as far as I can tell it's not the case.

Where it is called.

```
function startHandle(evt:MouseEvent):void{
  enemy = new Enemy(1090, 189);
  gotoAndStop(2);
  Player.stop();
  currentLevel = 1;
}
```

Then the Enemy class

```
public function Enemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int){
        trace(xLocation);
        trace(yLocation);
        // constructor code
        x = xLocation;
        y = yLocation;
        trace(x);
        trace(y);
}
```

The output I get from this is as follows.

> 1090
>
> 189
>
> 1090
>
> 189
>
> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on
> Enemy(). Expected 2, got 0.
>
> at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
>
> at
> Project_fla::MainTimeline/startHandle()

As far as I can tell it gets the two values, knows it has them, sets them. But still gives an error. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What code is on your second frame when doing the `gotoAndStop(2)`?

Comment: @BennettYeates The same code as the other one. My as runs over the length of the project (I presume bad practice, only just finding these things out the hard way). Want me to upload it somewhere?

Comment: @BennettYeates You want just the code files or the whole project file?

Comment: Any relevant files to the error will do.

Comment: @BennettYeates This is all of the code bar some lines that are just "stop();" or sending some basic data to my isAnimating() method. http://pastebin.com/HSkid2Pg and http://pastebin.com/76BcUmgu

Comment: Can you post your frame 2 code? Or is it identical to frame 1.

Comment: @BennettYeates Identical http://kyle93.co.uk/i/fd231.png

Comment: I don't see how you are getting that error with the code you provided. Would you be able to zip up the project and upload it?

Comment: You definitely have some code elsewhere that is causing this issue. Search for "new Enemy()" and see if anything turns up.

Comment: Also you should permit debugging in your project as the error will show a line number which will also help narrow down the problem. Maybe there is a stray enemy being created somewhere in the project.

Comment: @Nabren I've done that and not found it unfortunately.

Comment: @Scott I've been using "shift" "ctrl" and "enter" to go into debugging. Found the line but cant find how it is.

Comment: @BennettYeates Thank you so much for your help. However, as Vesper said I had left a MovieClip of it on a frame. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a pre-placed enemy on some frame. Since the default constructor for any `DisplayObject` descendant wants 0 arguments, anything created in Flash GUI makes Flash compiler to make a constructor call with 0 arguments. To circumvent this (and find that pesky enemy that throws you up) give default values for the constructor like this:

```
public function Enemy(xLocation:int=0, yLocation:int=0){
```

And watch when an enemy will appear at (0,0), debug that point and eliminate creation of any unneeded enemy instances.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I had managed to add one to a frame manually adding the MovieClip there. Thats why I had the error. Thank you so much :)